# While doing operator overloading on + and * on a bigint class, i get errors where qualifiers are discarded

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, bigint

> myint.cpp: In function `MyInt operator+(const MyInt&, const MyInt&)':
>   myint.cpp:193: error: passing`const MyInt' as `this' argument of`void MyInt::Grow()' discards qualifiers
>   myint.cpp:194: error: passing `const MyInt' as`this' argument of `void MyInt::Grow()' discards qualifiers
>   myint.cpp:219: error:`array' undeclared (first use this function)
>   myint.cpp:219: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
>   myint.cpp: In function `MyInt operator*(const MyInt&, const MyInt&)':
>   myint.cpp:252: error: passing`const MyInt' as `this' argument of`void MyInt::Grow()' discards qualifiers
>   myint.cpp:262: error: passing `const MyInt' as`this' argument of `void MyInt::Grow()' discards qualifiers
>   myint.cpp:290: error: invalid conversion from`int*' to `int'
>   myint.cpp:290: error:   initializing argument 1 of`MyInt::MyInt(int)'

are all my errors in case anyone can help.

and my code is here http://codepad.org/TlTFLjYd  for the cpp file

Comment: I think you need to `const` qualify those member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your line numbers in codepad don't match up with the errors you posted.

myint.cpp:193 (line 171): In `MyInt operator+ (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y)`, you call `x.Grow();`, however `x` is const.   You cannot modify a const object. Find a different way to implement your `operator+` that does not involve modifying `x` or `y`.  For example, start off with `MyInt z = x;` and then work on `z`.

myint.cpp:219 (line 197): you write `array.numArray`. However, you never declared `array`.
Earlier in your have some code:  (braces added by me for clarity):

```
if(x.maxSize > y.maxSize)
{
    MyInt array[x.maxSize];
}
else
{
    MyInt array[y.maxSize];
}
```

These arrays are local to the block that they are declared in, they no longer exist after this block.

Also, it is illegal to have a variable as an array size. Your compiler might implement it as a non-standard extension.

To fix all this , one option would be:

```
std::vector<MyInt> array ( std::max(x.maxSize, y.maxSize) );
```

myint.cpp:290 (line 216). Your function returns `MyInt`, however you call `return array;`, which is an array. I'm not sure what you meant to do here so I can't really recommend a fix. But I would guess that earlier you wanted an array of `int`, not an array of `MyInt`, and then you want to make this new array be the `numArray` of a `MyInt` that you return.